# Custom classloader trouble with getResources for names ENDING in slash

Tags: java, classpath, classloader, urlclassloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I am desperate for help but was unable to find anything on the web about this particular subject (many related ones that leave my particular problem unanswered).

Specifically, I need to be able to download code (jars) from a central and external code repository. This is done by the bootstrap code that needs to add this to the classpath of a class loader to be used thereafter. This is when we enter the subject that has been discussed so many times. I don't like hacks, so I tried the following:

**Attempt #1:** Create an instance of URLClassLoader configured for this purpose, then invoke the "rest" of the code through it.

Failure: There are 1.5 problems here (one may be the cause of another). One is that URLClassLoader, normally, prefers to load stuff from its parent. Some code has to exist in both, possibly different versions. If the code from the parent is used, it continues using the "outer" class loader for the rest of loading, which is not what we want, even when the initial loading is OK. Secondly, some third party libraries *seem* to access the system class loader directly, either by design or accidentally (may get it from one of the classes loaded by it).

**Attempt #2:** Create my subclass of the URLClassLoader that prefers self over the parent. Overrode loadClass, getResource, getResources, getPackage, getPackages... later other methods too to make sure of this.

Failure: Didn't help (enough). That third party code still couldn't load some *resources*.

**Attempt #3** Create another custom subclass of the URLClassLoader and set it as the system class loader using -Djava.system.class.loader=...

Failure: This worked better - went further, but still failed trying to get resources. This time it was different resources, though. I added logging to all the overridden methods to log their calls and resource names. Regular resources were MOSTLY found. Some still weren't, even though they are there (confirmed). But something I don't know about even though I tried hard to learn is about many calls with resource names that end with a slash. Some also have slashes where a dollar sign would normally appear (nested/inner class resources). Some examples that were requested but NOT found:

com/acme/foo/bar/ClassName/
com/acme/foo/bar/ClassName/InnerClassName/

When I run the downloaded code with all content on the initial/boot classpath (and do not use my classloader), everything works fine - thus my class loader breaks things, but I need it to work.

My closest guesses are:

1. Third party code gets hold of the true system class loader somehow, perhaps via some class that was loaded by it, then uses that. I don't see requests to it and they are bound to fail because it does not have the entire class path.
2. This business with resource names ending in slashes is the cause by being supported by the true system class loader but not by the URLClassLoader I am subclassing. I can only guess that the expected return URL somehow locates the collection of resources with that name as prefix. That would be tough to match, although possible. Furthermore, it appears that some slashes are in positions where a dollar sign separating the inner class name should be, i.e. in the above example (spaces added for clarity):

com/acme/foo/bar/ClassName **/** InnerClassName/

com/acme/foo/bar/ClassName **$** InnerClassName/

Please note that I cannot rely on hacking the actual system classloader by assuming that it is a subclass of the URLClassLoader and using reflection to call its addURL(URL) method.

Is there a way to make this work? Please help!

**UPDATE**

I just made an additional attempt. I created a dummy wrapper classloader (extending ClassLoader, not URLClassLoader) that only logs requests, then passes them on to the parent (public methods) or superclass (protected methods). I set this to be the system class loader and manually added the entire "inner" class path to the actual outer one, then tried to run the code. That works correctly, just as it does without the custom system class loader. What was logged also identified that even the system class loader return null for these resources ending in slashes for MOST of them, but not all. I did not check whether these also work in the my real code but guessing they may - as they were not the stumbling block. Somehow the custom system classloader is still being bypassed. How?

**UPDATE 2**

In my custom system class loaders I have let some classes come from the outer/true system class loader, e.g. those in java.lang. I am now suspecting that I should not have and that the inner "world" must be completely isolated. That would make it problematic, though, to communicate with it and all I would have left is reflection... but not sure whether that would even work - i.e. can there be more than one java.lang.Class and/or java.lang.Object?

Comment: Maybe you could have a peek at the source code of OneJar; it does pretty advanced stuff with classloading

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look later ... too tired now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given all constraints this does not appear entirely possible in a rock solid fashion as I wanted it:

a) Third party libraries may always "misbehave" and get hold of lassloaders they are not supposed to use one way or another. I looked at OneJar as suggested by fge but they have the same issue - they only detect a possibility of it.

b) There is no way to completely replace/hide the system class loader.

c) Casting the system class loader to a URLClassLoader may stop working at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you didn’t understand the class loader structure. Within an ordinary JVM of the current version, there are at least three class loaders:

1. The *bootstrap loader* which is responsible for loading the core classes. Since this involves classes like `Class` and `ClassLoader` itself, it can’t be represented by a `ClassLoader` instance. All classes whose `getClassLoader()` returns `null` were loaded by the bootstrap loader
2. The extension loader. It is responsible for loading classes within the `ext/` directory of the JRE. Afaik, it may vanish in future versions. Its parent loader is the bootstrap loader
3. The application loader. This is the one which will be returned by `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` and which will be used *if no other parent was specified*. In the current configurations, it’s parent is the extension loader, but maybe it will have the bootstrap loader as its direct parent in future versions

The conclusion is, if you want to reload your application’s classes without the delegation to the parent loader destroying your effort, you don’t need to manipulate the class loader’s implementation. You just have to specify the right parent. It’s as simple as

```
URLClassLoader cl=new URLClassLoader(urls, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());
```

That way, the new class loader’s parent will be the original application class loader’s parent, thus the already loaded application classes are not in the scope of the new loader while everything else works as usual.

Regarding the resources ending with a slash, they are rather uncommon. They may get resolved when they actually refer to a directory but that depends on the protocol of the URL and the actual handler for that protocol. E.g. it might work for `file:` URLs but usually doesn’t for `jar:` URLs unless the jar file contains pseudo-entries for directories. I’ve also seen it working for `ftp:` URLs.

Another thing to understand is that if one class directly refers to another class, its original defining class loader will be queried, not necessarily the application class loader. E.g. when the class `java.lang.String` contains a reference to `java.lang.Object` (it does), this reference will be directly resolved using the bootstrap loader as this is the defining loader of `java.lang.String`.

This implies that if you manipulate the parent lookup of a loader to not follow the standard parent delegation you are risking to resolve names to different runtime classes as the resolving of the same names when being referenced by classes loaded by the parent loader. You avoid such problems by following the standard procedure as in the solution above. The JRE classes will never contain references to your application classes and the new loader not having the original application loader as its parent will never interfere with the classes loaded by the original application loader.